# Simple Regular expression Java, brackets and doubles

Tags: java, regex, double

This is very basic but can't seem to find a answer when searching.

I have a string that's in the format:

```
[[[0.093493,51.6037],[0.091015,51.5956],[0.088596,51.5857]]]
```

The doubles inside the brackets are `[latitude coordinate,longitude coordinate]`.
From this I'd like to extract the coordinates. 
What should I put inside the search pattern if I use a Pattern/Matcher solution?
Assume that format with brackets is always correct but the doubles can vary in length.

Basicly what I want the code to do is: 
Find "[" left of a number, then find this "," and return what's in between 
**AND another searchpattern that:** 
find "," and "]" and return what's inbetween.

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple by using this regex:

```
\[(\d+\.\d+),(\d+\.\d+)\]
```

and repeat the `matcher.find()` till all matches are found.

You matches are in group #1 and group #2

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cJ7qC2/1)

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks a lot!
However I needed double backslashes, why is that?
And can you just briefly explain the code? I'm new to this and would like to understand what the acctual regex does.

Comment: In Java escape sequences need to be doubly escaped so above will be: `"\\[(\\d+\.\\d+),(\\d+\.\\d+)\\]"` in Java. This regex matches `[` followed by 1 or more digits followed by DOT and then again 1 or more digits followed by comma and then another set of co-ordinates finally ending with `]`